# Converting 2d Matrix to Single row DataFrame While Keeping Elements as Integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-conversion

I have a question regarding to converting a 2D matrix to a single row of Dataframe.

For example I have the following matrix (2D array) with integer elements

```
2d_array = [[0, 1, 1],[1, 0, 1],[1, 1, 0]]
```

Is there a way to convert it to a DataFrame like below, and keeping each element as integers?

```
df = 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0
```

I tried to flatten the 2D array first

```
flattened_array = 2d_array.flatten()
```

Then I use pandas.DataFrame

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(flatttened_array)
```

But the results gave me a single column Dataframe with elements of "numpy.float64" like below:

```
df = 
   0
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  1.0
3  1.0
4  0.0
5  1.0
6  1.0
7  1.0
8  0.0
```

Please help. Thank you so much!

Tommy

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([array.flatten()])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `[]`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([flattened_array])
df
Out[297]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0
```

Comment: Just curious, aren't you bored of answering simple questions like this? ;)

Comment: @cs95 getting bored recently . :-(

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! @WeNYoBen thanks for the help for my previous questions as well. Im still trying to pick up pandas

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try:

```
df[flatttened_array] = df[flatttened_array].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array(array).reshape(1,-1))
```